# cdkOverlay MatDialog In Angular doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to popup matdialog in overlay ... l have written every step required in Angular documentation to execute that..

1. add a link as a button in the calling component (HeaderComponent) and using click event

```html
<a mat-button (click)="openLoginForm()">
  <span class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></span> Login
</a>
```

2. importing all dialog models , the component which will be called in dialog (LoginComponent) and writing openLogin() method
3. doing all importing in (app-module-ts) and adding (LoginComponent) in declarations and entryComponents
   ----  but the matDialog is showing in the footer of the page not overlaying on the screen like the picture [image: problem]

Comment: Please format your question correctly its just one just block of text

Comment: done ..i'm sorry it's first time to me in stackoverflow

Comment: No problemo we all make mistakes

Comment: are you importing some .css? it's looks like missing `~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css` or some prebuilt-themes,e.g. `~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css` (the prebuitlt-themes yet included the overlay)

Comment: where? is this importing done in app.module.ts or in dialog component ts ?